# Changing store URL

Tags: magento-1.9

My existing domain, i.e. `domainA.com`, need to be moved into a sub folder of `domainB.com/newlocation`.

I understand that I can change the base URL for the domain under "`System > Configuration > General > Web`". But what other changes to I need to make given that domainA and domainB are on different servers?

Comment: Please refer link https://www.properhost.com/support/kb/30/How-To-Setup-Magento-With-Multiple-Stores-And-Domains